# C++ PKCS11 method C_Initiailize with arguments

Tags: c++, mingw, pkcs#11

We have an application developed in C++ for smartcard operations using PKCS11 and APDU. In this app, we tried to call the C_Initialize method with arguments. For this purpose, we are using the struct CK_C_INITIALIZE_ARGS and the code looks like this below:

```
CK_C_INITIALIZE_ARGS InitArgs =
{
NULL_PTR, /* CreateMutex */
NULL_PTR, /* DestroyMutex */
NULL_PTR, /* LockMutex */
NULL_PTR, /* UnlockMutex */
CKF_OS_LOCKING_OK, /* flags */
NULL_PTR, /* pReserved */
};
rv = context->pkcs11->C_Initialize(&InitArgs);
```

When we run the code, it return 0x7 error, which is bad arguments. We looked at many examples on Internet and looked at sample codes in other languages. They all direct to the usage as above. When we call it with NULL_PTR, it does not generate any error.

We are using MinGW for compiling the app and it's developed in Qt. When we look at the CreateMutex attribute, we see that MinGW has a macro named like that. When we rename that macro, it still does not work.

Thank you for your support in advance,

Best

Comment: Reading the documentation here https://www.cryptsoft.com/pkcs11doc/v220/structCK__C__INITIALIZE__ARGS.html I don't think the structure members (except the last) can be `NULL_PTR`.  I think it is trying to say that the whole structure is optional not the individual members.

Comment: As far as I remember this structure must be filled with proper and valid values. It is not designed to pass NULL in first four fields. The reference says to pass NULL instead of pointer to empty structure. I will try to find reference later and post a link.

Comment: Have you verified that your PKCS11 library is compiled with multi-threading support? Maybe it's returning the error because it cannot use the standard mutex mechanism.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. I checked with dll developers and as you pointed out, the dll does not support multi-thread operations. That's why it cannot allow args. So we initialize with NULL_PTR as args.